# Bring up select options from multiple select options

Tags: html, jquery, select

I have a list of accounts (unlimited) using select option with `class="selects"`

I want to `select` with `class="selects"` if the value of `<option value = '1'>` then it will appear `other select option`, and if the value of `<option value = '0'>` then the previous select option will be lost, I have succeeded do it

The problem is that i am using multiple `Akun`, i will give an example of 3 Akun but in my case the original is unlimited, i want for example when i select one account with `value = '1'` it will show `choose another option` in class 'box' itself, and the problem is that I'm here instead of appearing from all accounts not one by one

this is my code sample, i will accept if there is any other way besides this code i use, thanks

```js
$('.selects').on('change', function(){
    var kdbantu = $(this).val();
    
    if(kdbantu == '1'){
        $('.box-tx').fadeOut(0, function(){ $(this).remove(); });
        $(".box").append(`
            <select class="box-tx">
                <option>A</option> 
                <option>B</option> 
                <option>C</option> 
            </select>
        `);   
    }else{
        $('.box-tx').fadeOut(0, function(){ $(this).remove(); });
    }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Akun 1 :
<div class="box">
    <select class="selects">
         <option value="0"></option>
         <option value="0">0- Kas</option>
         <option value="0">0- Bank</option>
         <option value="1">1- Piutang</option>
         <option value="1">1- Jenis Usaha</option>
         <option value="0">0- Penjualan</option>
         <option value="1">1- Biaya</option>
    </select>
</div>

<hr>

Akun 2 :
<div class="box">
    <select class="selects">
         <option value="0"></option>
         <option value="0">0- Kas</option>
         <option value="0">0- Bank</option>
         <option value="1">1- Piutang</option>
         <option value="1">1- Jenis Usaha</option>
         <option value="0">0- Penjualan</option>
         <option value="1">1- Biaya</option>
    </select>
</div>

<hr>

Akun 3 :
<div class="box">
    <select class="selects">
         <option value="0"></option>
         <option value="0">0- Kas</option>
         <option value="0">0- Bank</option>
         <option value="1">1- Piutang</option>
         <option value="1">1- Jenis Usaha</option>
         <option value="0">0- Penjualan</option>
         <option value="1">1- Biaya</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I changed this line:

```
$(".box").append
```

To this:

```
$(this).parent().append
```

And I think it's achieved what you wanted.

Basically instead of grabbing every single **div** with the **.box** class, we just grab the one being interacted with the same way you did with **var kdbantu** and then from there we select the `parent()` node and append our change.